# Importing commit history from Bitbucket to Github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-commit

I wanted to import a project from Bitbucket to Github (both public repos).

However at some point in time (not the commit pointed by HEAD) some very large files were used which made the above process to fail.

So I just pushed the plain source code to gh.

I would like however to be able to have the project's commit history to gh.

Is there a way to do this?